# I am scraping the following website which contains java script but getting an error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a website but when I try to run the program, I get the following error. Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/danish-khan/webscraping/rgcrawler2/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Islamia_College_Peshawar/department/Department_of_Computer_Science/members')



chrome_options = Options()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rgw9_5fac070727fc2"]/div[3]/h5/a]')))
print(element.text)`
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resgt3.py", line 14, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rgw9_5fac070727fc2"]/div[3]/h5/a]')))
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: What information do you want from the page exactly?

Comment: Well. Your wait condition is timing out because the element couldn't be found, it seems. My guess is that the xpath of the element isn't static.

Comment: Your XPath is invalid. There's no such element on the page. What would your desired output be?

Comment: I want to scrape the user profiles names

Comment: There is an API for that: https://www.researchgate.net/plugins.DepartmentPluginConfig.html

Comment: But how to scrape through this api. Please hepl me.

Answer (score -1):

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rgw9_5fac070727fc2"]/div[3]/h5/a]')))
```

While page is loading your program waits `20` seconds  for XPATH element `'//*[@id="rgw9_5fac070727fc2"]/div[3]/h5/a]'` to appear.

If the XPATH element doesn't appear after defined time you get a Timeout error. Which is a good thing, otherwise your program would stuck forever if the XPATH element won't appear at all.

I think you should double check whether the provided XPATH is correct, or that it doesn't change over time.

Comment: There's no such element so the xpath is invalid.

Comment: Thank you I check the xpath which is wrong. i correct it and starts working.